# How do I unhide an element onclick from another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to unhide an element onclick from another page.

To break it down:
When you're on the Issue page, there is an 'Edit' button.
After clicking the 'Edit' button, it should take you to the Member page.
The Member Information should display for that member.
Thing is, the #memberInformation is currently hidden onload.
When I remove the hidden tag in the Chrome dev tools, the profile loads correctly.

I am unable to figure out how to unhide it onclick from another file.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#editBtn', function () { 
    var mid = $("#memberID").val();
    window.location = "new-member.html?mid=" + mid;                  
    $('#memberInformation').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

The #memberInformation ID belongs to the new-member.html file. The #editBtn ID belongs to the Issue.html file.

I am stumped!

Comment: You cannot interact directly with another page in the manner you're attempting. All you can do is store a flag somewhere (in the URL/localStorage/sessionStorage/server side via AJAX) then transfer the user to the other page and check for the presence of the flag you stored and show/hide the other element as needed as the next page is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I was to go the localStorage route, what would that look like?

Comment: I've added an answer below giving you an example of both halves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot interact directly with another page in the manner you're attempting. All you can do is store a flag somewhere (in the URL/localStorage/sessionStorage/server side via AJAX) then transfer the user to the other page and check for the presence of the flag you stored and show/hide the other element as needed as the next page is loaded

> If I was to go the localStorage route, what would that look like?

You would need to use `setItem()` on the issue.html page, then `getItem()` on the new-member.html page to toggle the `#memberInformation` element. Something like this:

```
// in issue.html
$(document).on('click', '#editBtn', function () { 
  var mid = $("#memberID").val();
  localStorage.setItem('memberId', mid);
  window.location.assign('new-member.html?mid=' + mid);    
});

// in new-member.html, when the page loads
jQuery(function($) {
  if ((localStorage.getItem('memberId')) {
    $('#memberInformation').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to display #memberInformation, only when the user clicked on the edit button in another page?
or you want to, make it visible on the page load by default.?

you can check the referrer page (using a new function on load) in new-member.html and if the referrer is Issue.html, remove the (hidden) class in new-member.html

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('exapmle.com/Issue.html') >= 0) { 
$('#memberInformation').removeClass('hidden');
 }
```

you can also pass the clicked button name (edit) on Issue.html trough URL parameter to forwarding link for checking in the new-member.html

and this is how you can do this with the localStorage

```
if (localStorage.getItem("memberId") !== "") { 
$('#memberInformation').removeClass('hidden');
 }
```